# PHP to MySQL query with multiple between clauses not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, between

```
$a = 51;
$b = 53;

$x = -2;
$y = 2;
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (latitude BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') 
        AND (longitude BETWEEN '$x' AND '$y')";
```

The query above retrieves no results, even though it should.
The strange thing is the following queries work:

```
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (latitude BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') 
        AND (longitude BETWEEN '$x' AND 2)"; 

 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (latitude BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') 
        AND (longitude BETWEEN -2 AND '$y')";
```

Replacing either of the second BETWEEN variables with the actual values returns the 
expected results 
but the query doesn't work with both variables together.

When echoing $query1 to make sure I've written the query correctly:

```
  "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE (latitude BETWEEN '51' AND '53') 
        AND (longitude BETWEEN '-2' AND '2')"
```

So I'm fairly confident that there aren't any syntax errors.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know SQL in and out in sleep but, sometimes you use quotes around those values and sometimes not. So I at least could imagine as the queries are different they come to different results. You don't seem to, so perhaps it's just an oversight of the quotes?

Comment: What is the data type of latitude and longitude?

Comment: @Hakre, if the quotes were the problem then queries 2 and 3 would not work, as quotes are used in those queries too.

Comment: @Nick They are doubles.

Comment: can you try to execute that query without PHP on the MYSQL cli ? did you get any result ? the query looks fine to me..

Comment: A) Don't use quotes on numbers. B) Don't use variables like `$x` in your query. Always use prepared statements with placeholder values.

Comment: @BazDaz: Well, just in theory: If `'2'` is `0` and `'-2'` is `0`, too. then I don't get any results `between 0 and 0` as there is no number between there, but I would get `between -2 and 0` perhaps. Not saying this is the case here (e.g. SQL could perhaps quote numbers as well), only it's more clear how I was guessing.

Comment: Your query works perfectly fine for me on MySQL 5.6 in phpMyAdmin. Are you using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: I've also just tested the code you supplied in PHP7 with PDO and MySQL 5.6 and it works fine too. You're going to need to supply more information: software versions, table structures, sample data and the exact code you are using.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6 in phpMyAdmin, with mysqli. The query is working for me in the MySQL cli too, just not with php. 

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, I am not sure what the problem is, but I will rewrite my code to see if there is any problem elsewhere and if it doesn't work, I will ask my lecturer for help. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Note that '-2' is a string. -2 is an integer